# Gscatter addon: is there a way to simulate wind?

Tags: particles, add-on, force-fields

I am using gscatter for grass weeds and other plants. With grasswald there was an option to animate wind. I cannot find anything like that with gscatter. Or is there a way to simulate the gscatter particle system with blenders built in force fields? Thank you!

Comment: Since GScatter is based on geometry nodes you can just extend node tree with a few nodes something like here https://youtu.be/yCGJbFVsbc0 or here https://youtu.be/WdgOL3qyPng

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can! First, you must make all the scattered objects one mesh (select them all, F3, search 'convert to mesh'). Then select the object, and add a displace modifier. Set the coordinates to object, and set the target object to a new empty. Animate the empty moving about 2x its distance over 200 frames. Then, for the displace modifier, add a new texture. Make it a banded texture (a wood one with bands), and then distort it a bit. There you go!

(In the attached .blend I used scattered planes for sake of time; you probably will use better assets! ;)

[image]

Comment: What a nice solution!